# Values from PHP simple XML

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml

I getting the following XML from an API and would like to use PHP to display it to a website.

```
<entityset>
<entity id="30751592" name="RFC-123456: name of change">
<template id="101" name="Request for Change" code="request_for_change"/>
<group id="62" name="Changes"/>
<attribute id="1108" name="Change requester" code="change_requester">
<reference id="19627173" name="Test name"/>
</attribute>
<attribute id="1109" name="Subject" code="subject">
<value>subject name</value>
</attribute><attribute id="1110" name="Description" code="description">
<value>Some description text</value>
</attribute>
<attribute id="1111" name="Status" code="status">
<value>2 - Approved</value>
</attribute>
<attribute id="1112" name="Change category" code="change_category">
<value>2 - Major</value>
</attribute>
</entity>
</entityset>
```

As you may notice, the format is a bit different depending on the data returned. Some will be returned as "value", some as a reference.

Data(`$data`) is coming from a http query (CURL). That part is working.
This is that I have tried so far:

```
$xml=simplexml_load_string($data);

$attributes = $xml->entity[0]->attribute;

print $attributes[0]; 
print $attributes[1]; 
print $attributes[2]; 
print $attributes[3];
```

How to fetch this as a correct array(associative is possible, but not a req.)?

Comment: is your goal to fetch only some attribute by certain value or to fetch them all?

Comment: Only some of the values are needed. The full result includes 50+ attributes and only some are needed.

Comment: As an example I would like the attribues where code=subject and code=description, or at least be able to refer to that specific value.

Comment: Can you be more specific on the format you want - "a correct array" doesn't mean anything to anyone who doesn't know what you're planning to do with it. Have you also read through [the examples in the official manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)?

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was specic when I said I required to print the values to a webpage. Based on the XML output, I guess I need to convert the data to something I can print (a value for subject, a value for description etc.). I have read the manual, but its been some years since I made something like this, so im abit rusty.

Comment: Well, you don't need to convert it to anything in order to print, you just need to, um, print it. Again, have a look over the examples in the manual, they show you how to do a lot more than your current code, and if you get stuck, you'll at least have a specific question to ask.